# Deselect all SWT radio buttons of a group

Tags: java, eclipse, radio-button, swt, radio-group

I have a couple of SWT `ToolItems` with style `SWT.RADIO` in a tool bar. I would like to deselect all of them programmatically using `toolItem.setSelection(false)`, but it is not possible. The `ToolItem` currently selected remains selected. I can select another ToolItem using `toolItem.setSelection(true)` and this will deselect the first one, but I could not find a way to deselect all of them, although when the GUI starts up, all of them are deselected. Does anyone know how to deselect all of them?

**Update:** I figured out what the problem is: I checked @rgeorge finding that `toolItem.setSelection(false)` works, if the toolbar is contructed with `ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(shell)`. However if I use the toolbar that can be obtained by `shell.getToolBar()`on the Mac (window frame unified toolbar), it does not work. Seems like a SWT incompatibility. Here is some code to reproduce the effect (change `useShellToolbar` to switch between cases on the Mac):

```
// taken from SWT Snippet47
package org.eclipse.swt.snippets;

import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class ToolbarRadioButtonGroupTest {

public static void main (String [] args) {

    boolean useShellToolBar  = true;

    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);

    Image image = new Image (display, 20, 20);
    Color color = display.getSystemColor (SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
    GC gc = new GC (image);
    gc.setBackground (color);
    gc.fillRectangle (image.getBounds ());
    gc.dispose ();

    Image image2 = new Image (display, 20, 20);
    color = display.getSystemColor (SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
    gc = new GC (image2);
    gc.setBackground (color);
    gc.fillRectangle (image2.getBounds ());
    gc.dispose ();

    ToolBar bar = null;
    if (useShellToolBar){
        bar = shell.getToolBar();
    }else{
        bar = new ToolBar (shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FLAT);
    }

    Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea ();
    bar.setBounds (clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 200, 32);
    int number = 3;
    final ToolItem[] items = new ToolItem[number];
    for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {
        ToolItem item = new ToolItem (bar, SWT.RADIO);
        item.setImage (image);
        items[i] = item;
    }

    ToolItem sep = new ToolItem(bar, SWT.SEPARATOR);

    ToolItem push = new ToolItem(bar, SWT.PUSH);
    push.setImage(image2);
    push.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener(){

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            for (ToolItem toolItem : items) {
                toolItem.setSelection(false);
            }

        }

    });

    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    image.dispose ();
    image2.dispose ();
    display.dispose ();
}
}
```

Comment: Deselect all? Only one radiobutton should be selected in a button group at a time...

Comment: You need to use a checkbox or some other control if you want them all deselected.  Radiobuttons when grouped will _always_ have an inherently selected button.

Comment: Am a newbie in SWT, but toolItem.setSelection(false) iterating through the radio items seems to work for me.  Please paste some code. Am using the SWT version which comes with Juno.

Comment: Nope, did not use any Group.  Can Groups be used for ToolItems in a Toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

```
btnB.setSelection(false);
```

You need to do that to every button, then you will deselect them all, try experementing using `buttonname.optionName(optionargs);`